# How can I get the corresponding error string from an FT_Error code?

Tags: freetype2

Given an FT_Error, is there a macro/function to return the corresponding error message string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is **No**, as far as I know.

You should create your own macro or function,
using macros defined in **fterrors.h**.
For example, the following code will work:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

const char* getErrorMessage(FT_Error err)
{
    #undef FTERRORS_H_
    #define FT_ERRORDEF( e, v, s )  case e: return s;
    #define FT_ERROR_START_LIST     switch (err) {
    #define FT_ERROR_END_LIST       }
    #include FT_ERRORS_H
    return "(Unknown error)";
}
```

Read **fterrors.h** (found in /usr/local/include/freetype2/ in my environment) for more detail and another example.

Comment: As of now, FreeType 2 has a comment about the use of `__FTERRORS_H__`. Instead, you should use `FTERRORS_H_`. I made an edit concerning this, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this question, `FT_Error_String` was introduced in FreeType2 version 2.10.1 to retrieve the error string of an FT_Error code.

```
FT_Error error = ...
if (error != 0)
{
    puts(FT_Error_String(error), stderr);
}
```

**Important:** You **must** define `FT_CONFIG_OPTION_ERROR_STRINGS` when compiling FreeType otherwise the function will return `NULL`.